# How to fix network connection high instability

Tags: networking

I am facing a strange issue with my ubuntu computer.
My Internet connection seams to work only a small instant every minute or so. Just enough to download POP3 emails but not enough to upgrade 100 MB packages.

I tried the following to assess the problem:

```
kadak@webcast:~$ ping 192.168.0.2
…
--- statistiques ping 192.168.0.2 ---
1382 paquets transmis, 219 reçus, +3 erreurs, 84,1534 % paquets perdus, temps 1410789 ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.499/2.597/123.335/11.061 ms,  tuyau 3
```

84% packet lost, it is huge.
192.168.0.2 is our DHCP server.

I tried the same on another computer running Windows 10, connected to the same wifi point of access, no package loss. So I cast out a network issue.

I tried to connect to the point of access through Ethernet cable instead of Wifi… same problem. So I cast out a Wifi hardware problem.

Here are my system information :

```
kadak@webcast:~$ uname -a
Linux webcast 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Would anybody have some tip to further investigate the issue?

Cheers,

Kadak

EDIT:
Here the result of syslog (interesting stuff I guess but too technical for me):

```
Jul  5 15:50:46 webcast systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  5 15:50:56 webcast systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jul  5 15:51:07 webcast whoopsie[1555]: [15:51:07] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul  5 15:51:29 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-68 noise=-95 txrate=1000
Jul  5 15:52:33 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-95 txrate=58500
Jul  5 15:53:17 webcast dbus-daemon[1925]: [session uid=1000 pid=1925] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=1923 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Jul  5 15:53:17 webcast dbus-daemon[1925]: [session uid=1000 pid=1925] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Jul  5 15:53:17 webcast systemd[1915]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Jul  5 15:53:17 webcast systemd[1915]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Jul  5 15:53:20 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-70 noise=-95 txrate=65000
Jul  5 15:53:48 webcast tracker-store[14704]: OK
Jul  5 15:53:48 webcast systemd[1915]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Jul  5 15:54:03 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-95 txrate=65000
Jul  5 15:54:27 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=-95 txrate=65000
Jul  5 15:54:46 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-70 noise=-95 txrate=65000
Jul  5 15:55:26 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=-95 txrate=65000
Jul  5 15:57:45 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-95 txrate=65000
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast NetworkManager[1197]: <info>  [1625493569.1809] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast whoopsie[1555]: [15:59:29] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast whoopsie[1555]: [15:59:29] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast whoopsie[1555]: [15:59:29] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast dbus-daemon[1196]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1197 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast dbus-daemon[1196]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul  5 15:59:29 webcast systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  5 15:59:30 webcast whoopsie[1555]: [15:59:30] online
Jul  5 15:59:39 webcast systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jul  5 15:59:50 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=-95 txrate=58500
Jul  5 16:00:37 webcast wpa_supplicant[1217]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-95 txrate=58500
```

Comment: Can you check syslog or journalctl for errors?

Comment: I checked journalctl for errors. Quite a lot but which service should I particularly look at?

Comment: I have no idea actually. But the "Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service" may be of interest. I would run the `journalctl -f` command on a terminal screen and leave it open. Then you may be able to correlate the messages displayed during the `ping` "timeout"s while a `ping` command is run on another terminal.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the problem is not there anymore. I just tried what you advised and 900 pings ran with 0% loss. Could it be an IP address conflict on the network and now the other user is down? How could I check that?
Also today before writing this post I tried a few things among which I removed snapd. Anyway, I will check in the next few days if the problem is really solved or not and let you know. Thank you.